# How to execute different actions based on the framework? (ASP.NET 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, migration, asp.net-core

Suppose that you have to migrate a C# application from the .NET framework to the new .NET Core, because you want to have some of it new capabilities.

You have your code base and you want to get fully working parts at a time, since it will be a lot of work migrating all at once. The main idea is to be *fully core* in a future.

My question is:

- Is there a way to check for functionality that is present in one framework but not in the other? Or to execute different actions based on the framework?

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense? I don't really get what your question is here.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, Is there a way to check for functionality that is in one framework but not in the other for example? Will edit my question.

Comment: Not that I know of off the top of my head, other than just try compiling for each target and see what works. If you find that some code doesn't work for a particular framework, you can use compiler preprocessor directives to compile particular pieces of code for a particular framework, as shown [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/3). If you're using Visual Studio, then Intellisense may give you some hints too.

Comment: Thanks!. Will take a look to that compiler preprocessor directives.

Comment: I suggest you watch some videos from this year and last year's Build, TechEd, DotNetConf, and Ignite events where they discuss .NET. Several of the videos have demonstrated using those directives. Those videos are mostly available on YouTube and Channel 9.

Comment: I found my answer there! Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **compiler directives** (#if) to check for symbols that correspond to the two frameworks. And it is also possible to target both frameworks.

If for instance you have code that uses resources that are not available as part of .NET Core, you can surround them in a conditional compilation directive.

Usage example of the compiler directives...

```
#if DNX451
    // Do something
#elif DNXCORE50
    // Do something
#else
#error No implementation for this target
# endif
```

Where `DNX451` represents the .NET Framework and `DNXCORE50` represents .NET Core.

See them in action [on this video at 36 min](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2015/ASPNET-5-Deep-Dive).

Comment: These #ifs appear not to work... the #else section is always active for me, even when I toggle the FWK in the nav bar, and also when I compile.

#if DNX451
        const int I = 3;
#elif DNXCORE50
        const int I = 2;
#else
        const int I = 1;
#endif

Comment: The names seem to have changed. DNX451 is NET451. s DNXCORE5 is  DOTNET5_4.

Comment: First link in answer is broken.