# How to Add Reference to System.Data.Services.Client in .Net 5 Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, dnx50

I am trying to add search to an Asp.Net 5 project. The search uses the Bing Search API.

As per the instructions in the "Bing Search API – Quick Start and Code Samples" I have downloaded a file called "BingSearchContainer.cs". This file has references to System.Data.Services.Client. The file is too big to put here but can be downloaded at https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/explore/getproxy/5ba839f1-12ce-4cce-bf57-a49d98d29a44.

I added references to System.Data.Services and System.Data.Services.Client as they were not included in the generic Asp.Net 5 (RC1) template I have used (in Visual Studio 2015) to create the site.

Although this removes the errors in the files themselves, the errors are still present in the error list and the project won't build or run.

If I hover over the using statement for System.Data.Services.Client at the top of the BingSearchContainer file it says ....DNX Core5.- Not Available.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Instead try downloading the API from NuGet. Looks like not all dependencies are installed properly.

Comment: Its part of the .net framework so its not possible to install as a nuget package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be aware of the platforms you're targeting. .NET Core is a new runtime, and there are no built-in libraries. Everything must be added (generally as a NuGet package), even things that were previously available from the [Standard Libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Libraries_(CLI)).

Check and see if the library you want is available on NuGet. If not, you'll need to find some sort of workaround or stop targeting .NET Core and just focus on the full .NET Framework.

Some workarounds

- Locate a different package that does what you want and is available for both .NET Core and the full .NET Framework
- Use System.Data.Services.Client on full .NET Framework and an alternative framework for .NET Core, and use [compiler directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438371/how-to-execute-different-actions-based-on-the-framework-asp-net-5) to target specific blocks of code at specific versions of the framework
- Location the source for System.Data.Services.Client and try porting it to .NET Core. You should probably double check with Microsoft about this to see if they have plans to move it over already, as well as to see if there's anyone else that might help you with it
- Just compile your project for .NET Framework, and don't compile for .NET Core